# Is there any way to get a bot to create a guild on Discord?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js V12, and I am trying to get my bot to create a guild with a channel in it. However, I'm unable to fix this error "TypeError: channels is not iterable". This is my current code:

```
client.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.content == "?createGuild") {
        let guild = await client.guilds.create("Test Guild", {channels: {id: 1, type: "text", name: "invite-channel"}}).catch(err => {console.log(err)});        
        let guildchannel = await guild.channels.find(cha => cha.name == "invite-channel");
        let invite = await guildchannel.createInvite({maxAge: 0, unique: true, reason: "Testing."});
        message.channel.send(`https://discord.gg/${invite.code} is the server I created!`);
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Client.guilds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=guilds)[`.create`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=create) takes as a second parameter an options [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). `Options.channels` takes an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), containing multiple objects, each object representing a channel. You are providing an [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) instead.

*Note that everyone can create a Guild since you have no restrictions on this command.*

---

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.content == "?createGuild") {
        const Guild = await client.guilds.create("Test Guild", {
            channels: [
                {"name": "invite-channel"},
            ]
        });

        const GuildChannel = Guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name == "invite-channel");
        const Invite = await GuildChannel.createInvite({maxAge: 0, unique: true, reason: "Testing."});
        message.channel.send(`Created guild. Here's the invite code: ${Invite.url}`);
    };
});
```